# Escape ":" in Python?

Tags: python, escaping, pytumblr

I'm using Python (and Pytumblr) and trying to extract a certain string from some returned data, but the string I am searching for includes ":" in it. Whenever I run my script I get the error:

```
File "myfile.py", line 22
    if re.search('^ion': u'..', u'b', line) :
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my code:

```
import pytumblr
import re

returned = client.submission('blog') # get the submissions for a given blog

sch = open('returned')
for line in sch:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('^ion': u'..', u'b', line) :
        print line
```

Is there another error in this code or is there a way to escape ":" that I don't know about? I'm pretty new to Python but I didn't think : needed to be escaped.

Comment: `:` does not matter, but `'` does.

Comment: Please provide an example of the data you are trying to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a syntax error because your colon is not part of the string. The single quote `'` mark is closing off the string. Your first argument is being parsed as:

```
'^ion'       - String 1: ^ion
:            - Syntactical colon
 u           - The syntactical character u,
               indicating you intend for the
               following string literal to be
               in unicode
'..'         - String 2: ..
```

If you want your single quote at the end of `^ion` to be a part of the string, you either need to escape *that* with a backslash `'^ion\':` or, alternatively, use double quotes around the string itself. Since Python accepts both single and double quotes for string literal markers, `'hello'` and `"hello"` mean the same thing. Making `'"hello world"'` and `"'hello world'"` both legal strings.

If the regex is the pain point here, there's lots of literature and tooling out there to help. I recommend [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use double quotes:

```
re.search("^ion': u'..', u'b", line):
```

Or escape `'`:

```
re.search('^ion\': u\'..\', u\'b', line):
```